# Ubuntu 20.042 LTS freezing and crashing with EXT4-fs error: --ext4_find_entry: 1535

Tags: crash

I have an older Acer Swift 3 (dualboot) which started freezing and crashing with the following error message:

EXT4-fs error(device sda5): __ext4_find_entry: 1535: inode...
error messages
[image]
I allready reinstalled Ubuntu but it still appears. SMART-Test seems to be ok. /var/crash shows no entry. Anybody has I suggestion, what else I could try?. I'm moor or less a newby to Linux.

Comment: Looks like there are an error on that filesystem. Boot on a live media (USB/DVD - the one you installed from) and run `fsck /dev/sda5`. This will fix any "soft" errors in the filesystem. If it is a hardware problem (disk is broken) it might not help.

Comment: Thanks, I tiied this, but it retuned no error. I guess it's a hardware thing then.

Comment: If `fsck` didn't give you any relief, then it's possible it's hardware, yes.

Comment: Is it possible that these crashes are related to the kernel version? I just tried the older version(5.8.0-41 instead of -42), now everything workes fine.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem, and I have tried to fix it with badblock command. e.g
steps:

1. Unmount your ssd/disk
2. Open terminal and typing `sudo badblock -sv /dev/nvme1p..`
3. Waiting for readonly check test for inode.
4. As if exist error nodes/indexs, try to fix according to operation tips.
5. Restart yours laptop/pc to use.
6. Observe for a few days when you used laptops/pc.